# No equality on GroupBy item

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by, equality

I am iterating through an enumerable of `IGrouping` and performing an equality check on each entry. However, when stepping through this code I can see that the equality check is never met.

```cs
namespace EqualityGroupingTest
{
    public class Reading
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public int Measurement { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var readings = new List<Reading>()
            {
                new Reading() {Id = 1, Label = "A101", Measurement = 3},
                new Reading() {Id = 2, Label = "A101", Measurement = 5},
                new Reading() {Id = 3, Label = "A101", Measurement = 8},
                new Reading() {Id = 4, Label = "A102", Measurement = 2},
                new Reading() {Id = 5, Label = "A102", Measurement = 5},
                new Reading() {Id = 6, Label = "A102", Measurement = 9}
            };

            var offset = -1;
            var grouping = readings.GroupBy(i => i.Label);
            foreach (var group in grouping)
            {
                var range = (group.Last().Measurement - group.First().Measurement);

                if(group.Equals(grouping.Last()))
                {
                    range += offset;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code that checks whether I'm looking at the last grouping is never met. I can alter this code from:

`if(group.Equals(grouping.Last()))`

To:

`if(group.Key.Equals(grouping.Last().Key))`

This fixes the problem but I do not understand why the check on `IGrouping` is not met. I can see that the hashcodes between the variable `group` and `grouping.Last()` are different in the watch window but again, I'm not sure why this is. If anyone could clarify why this is happening I'd like to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `grouping` is a deferred executed LINQ query which is executed again in the loop at `grouping.Last()`. This will create new instances of the internal class [`Grouping`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,7bb231e0604c79e3,references), so `Object.ReferenceEquals` never returns `true`.

You could add them to a collection, for example by appending `ToList`:

```
var grouping = readings.GroupBy(i => i.Label).ToList();
```

Be careful if you find the sentence "This method is implemented by using deferred execution" in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8). This means that you are not getting a collection but a "query" which will always be executed if you use it(for example by using a `foreach` loop, or non-deferred methods like `First`/`Last` or `ToArray`/`ToList`). 
But if you append other deferred methods like `Select`,`Where` or `OrderBy` it will not be executed. Then you are just building the final *query*.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I invoked the grouping by calling `ToList` and this now works.